# VBA интеграция офисных приложений посредством Active X. Объект Automation

Tags: excel, vba, activex

Здравствуйте, суть такова, есть экселевская книга с формочками и кнопочками и презентация из PowerPointa, состоящая из одного слайда, сохраненная в режиме демонстрации. Нужно через Active X сделать так, чтобы при открытии этой книги, проигрывалась презентация, а потом выполнялась своя собственная логика экселевской книги. 
В методичке пример выглядит так:

```
Public Sub zastavka()  
Dim ppApp As Object  
Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")  
ppApp.Visible = True  
ppApp.Presentations.Open "G:\shop_ppt.ppsx"  
ppApp.Quit  
End Sub
```

Но он не работает, презентация сразу же закрывается. Если убрать последнюю строчку, презентация работает, но потом все надо вручную закрывать. К тому же на офисе 2013 этот код только открывает редактор PowerPoint'a с презентацией не в режиме просмотра, а в учебке-то сразу начинает проигрывать. Помогите, зачет горит, VBA увидел неделю назад, и ни черта не понимаю.